# Mockito - verifying a stub

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a stub that is used across different test cases and I need to verify that certain methods are not called in some of these test cases.

The problem I'm having with mocks I get through `Mockito.mock()` is that calling their methods have no effect.

So, can I somehow mock a stub so that method calls are executed as they should and at the same time they are logged so that they can be verified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is spies. See here: http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html (#13 in the list).

Comment: new link is: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13